# Visual Studio changes IISExpress settings in csproject

Tags: visual-studio, iis-express, csproj

The problem with IISExpress settings appears when something is added/removed from project, i.e. when csproject file must be updated. But along with necessary changes Visual Studio 2017, version 15.7.6 unexpectedly resets /Project/PropertyGroup/IISExpress* values.

Before:

```
<IISExpressAnonymousAuthentication>enabled</IISExpressAnonymousAuthentication>
<IISExpressWindowsAuthentication>disabled</IISExpressWindowsAuthentication>
<IISExpressUseClassicPipelineMode>false</IISExpressUseClassicPipelineMode>
```

After:

```
<IISExpressAnonymousAuthentication>
</IISExpressAnonymousAuthentication>
<IISExpressWindowsAuthentication>
</IISExpressWindowsAuthentication>
<IISExpressUseClassicPipelineMode>
</IISExpressUseClassicPipelineMode>
```

This project is maintained by a team of developers, so I would not like to make unintentional changes to shared IISExpress settings, but now I'm forced to manually undo them before committing.

Comment: A few options: 1) complain to Microsoft, and see if they can fix (less likely), 2) move such settings to `.user` file, so they live on each machines, and usually not touched by VS. 3) Do whatever you do right now. There is almost no way to give you an exact answer here.